# How can I parse and replace all malformed HTML Entities in an SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008, replace, html-entities

I have a database that had data parsed into it. During parseing ampersands and semi-colons were removed which messed up a bunch of HTML Entities.

For example, I now have data stored like so:

```
#7779avaf#299
```

Which should be:

```
&#7779;avaf&#299;
```

I started replacing some of these like so:

```
REPLACE ( FIELD1, '#7779' , '&#7779;' )
```

However, I have to write a new replace for every entity. I'm not very good with RegEx. Is there a way I can match all possible combinations of # followed by 3 or 4 digits and replace it with &# followed by the same 3 or 4 digits and then a semi colon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a regular expression to extract all the matching target text:

```
(#\d{3,4})
```

You can then use the list it would generate to generate your `REPLACE` statements, or [figure out the syntax to use the backtracking feature](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/) of your regular expression engine to dynamically wrap the matched group with a `&` and `;`

[T-SQL Regular Expression Workbench](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/) has some examples of [how to `SELECT`](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/#third) using a regular expression like above. As well as [how to `REPLACE`](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/#fourth).

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that every # belongs to an HTML entity in a given field, you can do this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET [FIELD1] = REPLACE(FIELD1, '#', '&#')
UPDATE myTable SET [FIELD1] = STUFF(FIELD1, (CHARINDEX(FIELD1, '#') + 5), 0, ';')
```

If not, you'll probably need to create a CLR function for a REGEX match because SQL doesn't support it natively.